# Animated gif not moving in IE

Tags: javascript, animated-gif

The animated gif (spinner.gif) in this javascript is not moving in Internet Explorer. I have tried with version 8, 9 and 10. It is working fine in Chrome.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var h1 = Builder.node("h1", "Title");
    var h3 = Builder.node("h3", "Text");
    var node = Builder.node("div", {style: "border: 1px solid #0F0; text-align: center"});
    var img = Builder.node("img", {src: '../js/modalbox/spinner.gif'});
    node.appendChild(h1);
    node.appendChild(h3);
    node.appendChild(img);            
</script>
```

`Builder` is from http://madrobby.github.io/scriptaculous/builder/

`node` is added in my jsp-page when the button below is pushed.

```
<h:commandButton value="Button" actionListener="#{stuffBean.createStuff}" onclick="onSubmit();if (window.confirm('Text')) {body.style.cursor='wait';Modalbox.show(node, {title:'', overlayClose: false, width: 300}); return true;} else {return false;}"/>
```

How do I get it to move in IE version 8, 9 and 10?

Comment: If you just load the file directly in the browser does it work? Where does the `node` get added to the document in that code?

Comment: What is `Builder`?

Comment: @epascarello I added information about where node is added.

Comment: @Neal I added information about Builder.

Comment: @user1766169 it doesnt look like Builder has been updated in almost 5-10 years. Consider using VanillaJs or a newer library to solve your issues.

Comment: It would help if you upload gif somewhere to see it